# Issues with Math.abs in Chess code for Rook

Tags: java, chess

When I run my code `Rook` is jumping over pieces diagonally when that's not allowed. Rook is only allowed to move any number of squares horizontally or diagonally. Can anyone help me out? I believe the issue is with the Math.abs section at the top.

Here is my code for the class Rook:

```java
public boolean canMove(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {
    if (Math.abs(startx - endx) == 1 || Math.abs(starty - endy) == 1) {
        return true;
    } else if (Math.abs(startx - endx) == 1 && Math.abs(starty - endy) == 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (Math.abs(startx - endx) == Math.abs(starty - endy)) {
        return false;
    } else if (starty > endy) {
        for (int y = starty - 1; y > endy - 1; y = y - 1) {
            if (Chess.position[startx][y] != null) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else if (starty < endy) { //Check downwards
        for (int y = starty + 1; y < endy + 1; y = y + 1) {
            if (Chess.position[startx][y] != null) { ///
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else if (startx > endx) { //Y isn't changing only X is - moving left
        for (int x = startx - 1; x > endx - 1; x = x - 1) {
            //if(Chess.position[starty][x] != null){
            if (Chess.position[x][endy] != null) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else if (startx < endx) {
        for (int x = startx + 1; x < endx; x = x + 1) {
            //  for(int x = startx + 1;x < endx+1; x=x+1) {
            if (Chess.position[x][endy] != null) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (starty == endy || startx == endx) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that method `canMove` is returning **true** when it should be returing **false**? Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code? By the way, [Rook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)) cannot move diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the chessboard to find out what are the rook movements. For example, if the rook is in the position D5, these are the offsets:

```
   A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H
(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) (0, 4) (0, 5) (0, 6) (0, 7)  8
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7)  7
(2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6) (2, 7)  6
(3, 0) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6) (3, 7)  5
(4, 0) (4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3) (4, 4) (4, 5) (4, 6) (4, 7)  4
(5, 0) (5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3) (5, 4) (5, 5) (5, 6) (5, 7)  3
(6, 0) (6, 1) (6, 2) (6, 3) (6, 4) (6, 5) (6, 6) (6, 7)  2
(7, 0) (7, 1) (7, 2) (7, 3) (7, 4) (7, 5) (7, 6) (7, 7)  1
```

Note that the rook, being in the position (**a**, **b**) can only move to the position (**x**, **y**) if

- **y** is equal to **b** and **x** is not equal to **a** (look at the D column)
- **x** is equal to **a** and **y** is not equal to **b** (look at the 5 row)

Therefore, your condition should be something like this:

```
public boolean canMove(int startx,int starty,int endx,int endy){
    // Only triggers if the x-axis is the same (i.e. the rooks move only in the horizontal)
    if ((startx == endx) && (starty != endy)) {
        return true;
    }
    
    // Only triggers if the y-axis is the same (i.e. the rooks move only in the vertical)
    if ((startx != endx) && (starty == endy)) {
        return true;
    }
    
    // Insert your additional chessboard conditions, to check
    // if there are occupied pieces between the start and the end

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Rooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)) cannot move diagonally.

There's a lot of things that causing you the problem. It's not `Math.abs()`, it's your code that is causing the bug.

**Issue 1:**

```
    if(Math.abs(startx-endx)==1 || Math.abs(starty-endy)==1){
        return true;
    }
    else if(Math.abs(startx-endx)==1 && Math.abs(starty-endy)==1){
        return false;
    }
```

Your first condition will return `true` if any of the `Math.abs(start-end)` is `1`. So the second condition will **never** be checked and you'll always get `true` for that case.

**Issue 2:**

In rest of the blocks inside your method, you tried:

```
else if (starty>endy) {
    for (int y = starty - 1; y > endy-1; y = y - 1) {
        if (Chess.position[startx][y] !=null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Although you wrote a for loop, your loop will never iterate more then once as you're returning `true` or `false` inside the loop block in either way, whether the condition meets or not.

**Issue 3:**

In the last condition, you wrote:

```
if(starty == endy || startx == endx){
    return false;
}
```

I don't know why you wrote that. Because you must have one of the `starty-endy` and 'startx-endx` pair same and other pair different to make a move of the rookie. So this checking is totally unnecessary.

**What you can do?**

You can sum up the whole conditions in just the following blocks and the helper method `checkChessBoard` to remove redundant codes:

```
public boolean canMove(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {
    boolean xFixed = (startx == endx && starty != endy);
    boolean yFixed = (startx != endx && starty == endy);

    if (!(xFixed || yFixed)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (xFixed) {
        return starty > endy ? checkChessBoard(startx, endy, starty, xFixed) :
                checkChessBoard(startx, starty, endy, xFixed);
    } else {
        return startx > endx ? checkChessBoard(starty, endx, startx, xFixed) :
                checkChessBoard(starty, startx, endx, xFixed);
    }
}

private boolean checkChessBoard(int fixed, int start, int end, boolean xFixed) {
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
        if (Chess.position[xFixed ? fixed : i][xFixed ? i : fixed] != null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```